# What is a good English translation for "老乡"?

Tags: translation, word

In what contexts can `老乡` used? How do they translate to English?

Comment: I guess you are not satisfied with "fellow townsman; fellow villager; sb from the same hometown"?  http://www.mdbg.net/chindict/chindict.php?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=%E8%80%81%E4%B9%A1

Comment: yeah, expecting some authentic expression; maybe there isn't one

Comment: I guess "fellow townsman" and "fellow villager" will be the best what you can get

Comment: Can we improve the question body? @pegausbupt please write more context and add detail.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but it's still insufficient. The question is too open-ended. @pegausbupt In what situation you'd use this translation? We don't want answers to list every single possible situation.

Comment: find "good translations" at jukuu: 58 example sentences

Comment: @Alenanno's remark is still relevant.  老乡 has too many senses, and of course no one English phrase suits all.

Answer (score 5):

An appropriate word would be [countryman](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/countryman?s=t&ld=1064)

> noun, plural countrymen.
>
> ```
>  1. a native or inhabitant of one's own country.
>  2. a native or inhabitant of a particular region.
>  3. person who lives in the country.
>  4. an unsophisticated person, as one who lives in or comes from a rural
>     area; rustic.
> ```

Meaning from [Baidu](http://baike.baidu.com/view/354029.htm):

```
1、老乡的范围可大可小。比如在市里看到同一县的人，在省里看到同一市的人，在全国看到同一省的人，都可以算做老乡
2、以前解放军对百姓们的称呼。
```

Translated to English:

> 1. The usage of this word is flexible. For example, it can be applied to those living within the same district of a city, the same city
>      within a province, or the same province within the country.
> 2. The PLA used to address the commoners this way.

Usage example:

```
无论是因为工作漂泊在外，还是因为求学进去在外，一句老乡拉近了你我彼此之间的距离。
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the meaning "1" for countryman is dominant, so this doesn't work 100% as a translation for 老乡.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be using technical translation. Because `老乡` the word itself is very informal and make people feel warm and relax.

I would use `pals from hometown` if I need to explain this word to foreigner

Comment: But 老乡 may not be pals, just people from the same hometown.

Answer (score 0):

老乡 is a bit narrower than, but related to the Yiddish לאַנדסמאַן - landsman (with "a"s like the "o" in bottle and a true "s" like pass, not a /z/ like pans).  That word, according to Wikipedia, has made it into English as [landsman](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/landsman), though I don't think it's widespread (I haven't heard anyone but my mom use it - and then only when describing the Yiddish word).

If you don't like that, maybe an even broader term like compatriot, perhaps? or homey?

Answer (score 0):

The English term that is closest to 老乡 is "country folk" or "countryman"

> http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/folk
>
> 3. plural :  a certain kind, class, or group of people : old folks | |just plain folk | **country folk**

**Folk** is always plural.

- You can describe or address a group of 老乡 as "folks"
- to describe one 老乡 , you can say "that countryman"
- to address one of your own 老乡, you can say " Hey, fellow countryman!"

Answer (score 0):

In Guangdong, especially in Guangzhou the term 老鄉 is used ironically as a derogatory term for someone from a different province or by Cantonese speakers for someone who don't speak the language.

Comment: good explanation

Answer (score 0):

Probably best to use "someone/people from the same/my hometown".

There are some other options which would work in specific contexts, though:

> **paisan**

which is an Italian loanword to American English. It can mean someone from the same hometown or region.

You could even use:

> **laoxiang** or **lao-hsiang**

as long as you explain it to anyone who might not be familiar. It has become used in English [since the 1990s](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=paisan%2CPaisan%2Claoxiang&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpaisan%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CPaisan%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Claoxiang%3B%2Cc0).

And perhaps, lightheartedly:

> **hometown mafia**, analogous to phrases such as **PayPal mafia**

Answer (score 0):

I can't help but think of "homeboys"/"homies"

Comment: This does not mean what you think it means - 老乡 means someone who was from the same region that the person was born/raised in, and "homeboy" definitely doesn't mean that.